# having trouble in understanding when QuerySets are evaluated in django

Tags: django, django-queryset, lazy-evaluation

Consider the following sample

```
data = Employee.objects.all()
for i in data:
   print i.name
```

from my understating here it hits database for each loop. I am not sure weather i am right or wrong.

Next doubt is

```
data = Employee.objects.get(id=1)
```

in this case when it will hit the database? and what if i stored data in to another variable?

what if i did

```
data = Employee.objects.all()
data1 = []
data1 = data
for i in data1:
    print i
```

what is the difference between above and this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the first case it will hit database at the start of the for loop, more precisely at the first loop.
2. In the second, it will not hit the database yet because the QuerySet isn't evaluated yet. QuerySets are lazy and are evaluated in the following cases:

> - The first time you iterate over them
> - When you slice them. for instance: `Post.objects.all()[:3]`
> - When you pickle or cache them
> - When you call `repr()` or `len()` on them
> - When you explicitly call `list()` on them
> - When you test it in a statement such as `bool()` , `or` , `and` , or `if`

From the book [Django by Example, p. 21](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YSIL51S)

For more on when the QuerySets are evaluated see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Answer (score 10):

1. In your first case the queryset is evaluated (and therefore hits the database) [once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) - at the start of the loop.
2. The `get()` calls will hit the database immediately. All model data will be fetched and you won't be hitting database when accessing model attributes (unless they are `ForeignKeys`). If you have stored it in the another variable, these instances are not linked in any way. For example:

   ```
   var1 = Employee.objects.get(pk=1)
   var2 = Employee.objects.get(pk=1)

   var1.name = 'var1'
   var2.name = 'var2'
   var2.save()

   print var1.name
   >>> 'var1'
   ```

If you'd like to get the latest saved object's version, you can call the [`refresh_from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) method

```
    var1.refresh_from_db()
    var1.name
    >>> 'var2'
```

3. There's no difference between 1) and 3), since in 3) you just make the queryset accessible via `data1` variable. It doesn't get evaluated on assignment, but does on iteration.

Comment: in 1 it will hit the database only once na?

Comment: Yes, uless your `name` attribute is not a `ForeignKey` or someting. Clarified the answer a bit.

Comment: ok in get it hits the database immediately. right? print var1.name, print var2.name in this case it will hit database two times or one time or none because it already hit on get query?

Comment: Good question. You're right, you'll hit the db only once, right when you call `get()`. When you've fetched the object, accessing its properties won't result in additional queries. Updated the answer.